# Extremely powerful jaws

Tags: xenobiology, fauna, biochemistry

How my alien creature jaws crush toughest metal alloys in our world with ease ? what structure could it need to produce such bite? and what materials is it possible reinforced that allows it to bite and crush through strongest and toughest metals with very ease?

Comment: Cold Rolled Steele (think cyber truck) can have a tensile strength in the range of 217,556 psi. There is no living creature ever that is able to generate a bite force that is within an even within an order of magnitude of this value. A T-Rex with a bite force of 8000 psi is 4% of the tensile strength of some cold rolled steel. https://www.jfe-steel.co.jp/en/products/sheets/catalog/b1e-002.pdf

Comment: Given the "hardness" of some cold rolled steel, this same t-rex would manage little more than a 2.5mm radius dent.

Answer (score 3):

Saltwater crocodiles have the highest recorded bite strength of 3,700 pounds per square inch (psi), or 16,460 newtons, of bite force. This is enough to break steel. Steel can withstand about 3k–5k PSI per inch of steel. Of extinct animals the T-rex has a supposed bite strength of 8,000 Pounds per square inch.

[image]

If you want a different structure compared to normal jaws look no further than [machines that bend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97t7Xj_iBv0). In mechanical engineering, a compliant mechanism is a flexible mechanism that achieves force and motion transmission through elastic body deformation. A great example of compliant mechanisms: this plier (picture above) has a supposed strength ratio of 30:1. Simply imagine the flexible parts as bones and cartilage.

I'm not good at math but I hope this helped.

Comment: Good, but you should be looking for indentation hardness of materials, not tensile strength when determining their resistance to biting.

Answer (score 3):

> How my alien creature jaws crush toughest metal alloys in our world with ease ?

Magic, more or less.

We already produce materials that are astonishingly difficult to machine, and so have to resort to various clever ways of making them in the right shape in the first place or using shaping processes that aren't simply mechanical. One does not simply mill or chop [inconel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconel), for example! Water jets, laser cutters and electrical-discharge machining is done instead.

Practically, there's nothing your beasties could be made of that would be strong and tough enough unless they were absolutely *gigantic*, and that comes with its own problems.

Superhard materials do exist, and there may even be a way to biologically synthesize them ([bacterial carborundum](https://www.businessinsider.com/silicon-carbide-bacteria-chemistry-2016-12), for example) but such materials are brittle and are better suited for abrasive work... grinding things away with fresh abrasive teeth being grown continuously to replace the ones worn down or cracked by contact with the kinds of extremely tough material you're trying to destroy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Harder teeth. The strongest biological substance is a limpet's tooth: https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-31500883
2. Sharper teeth
3. Shorter jaw with bigger muscle: “[The strength of the jaguar’s bite is due to the arrangement of its jaw muscles, which, relative to weight, are slightly stronger than those of other cats. In addition – also relative to weight – its jaws are slightly shorter, which increases the leverage for biting.](https://www.discoverwildlife.com/animal-facts/mammals/which-big-cat-has-the-strongest-bite/)”
4. [Fast-twitch fibers](https://www.ibtimes.com/human-evolution-made-chimpanzees-stronger-humans-myth-muscular-strength-2559438)